# improper integral with floor function

Tags: integration

This is the question: 
[image]

The solution's first step is:

[image]

I really don't understand this step and I wanted a further explanation. I understand how to do everything afterwards but I'm a little confused about this step

Answer (score 1):

What they are doing is breaking the integral up into segments of length $1$.  For example, if $x\in [3,4), \lfloor x \rfloor=3$  This interval corresponds to the $n=3$ piece of the sum.  Each piece of the sum corresponds to a segment where the floor function is constant at $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} n e^{-x} dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^\infty e^{-x} dx$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned} \int_0^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor e^{-x} dx &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \lfloor x \rfloor e^{-x}dx\\ &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \lfloor x \rfloor e^{-x}dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} ne^{-x}dx .
\end{aligned}$$